# Can't insert new row into postgres database table?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have an issue, I'm trying to insert a new row into a postgres database table and get the following error

```
ERROR:  duplicate key violates unique constraint "n_clients_pkey"
```

Here my query

```
insert into n_clients(client_name) values( 'value');
```

I'm using postgres 8.1.11

```
 PostgreSQL 8.1.11 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)
```

Here's the structure for my table

```
                                                Table "public.n_clients"
   Column    |           Type           |                               Modifiers                               
-------------+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                  | not null default nextval(('public.n_clients_id_seq'::text)::regclass)
 client_name | character varying(200)   | not null
 moddate     | timestamp with time zone | default now()
 createdate  | timestamp with time zone | default now()
Indexes:
    "n_clients_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

and the sequence

```
Sequence "public.n_clients_id_seq"
    Column     |  Type   
---------------+---------
 sequence_name | name
 last_value    | bigint
 increment_by  | bigint
 max_value     | bigint
 min_value     | bigint
 cache_value   | bigint
 log_cnt       | bigint
 is_cycled     | boolean
 is_called     | boolean
```

Comment: Can you add your CREATE TABLE command for the n_clients table.

Comment: I updated my question, please have a look at my tables structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This row exists already, therefore you cannot insert it. What is the primary key of your relation? Is it a sequence? If so, maybe it got stuck (maybe you imported data). You should reset it manually to the next free ID available (e.g., if the maximum ID is 41, you should do: SELECT setval('your_seq', 42);) then try again.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a [UNIQUE constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#AEN2016) on your table, that your insert is violating -- ie, considering the name of your table and index, you are probably trying to insert a client that already exists in your table.

Answer (score 0):

Typically one gets into this situation by manually adding a record with an id field that matches the current value for the sequence.  It's easy to introduce this by some common dump/reload operations for example.  I wrote an article about correcting for this sort of error across the entire database at [Fixing Sequences](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Fixing_Sequences).

Answer (score 0):

The PostGresSQL should have a primary key while creating a DB , so you are not able to add anything include then only you can add data manually

Answer (score -1):

8.1 version is dated.
8.4 displays a much better error message :

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "master_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.